Odoo 17: Create sales order with gross prices
I try to import a sales order from an Shopware 6.5 online shop. Because of different tax calculations that lead to rounding errors, the total price of the order can differ by multiple cents.
For odoo itself there is the option with a B2C pricelist: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/applications/finance/accounting/taxes/B2B_B2C.html
But I create the Odoo 17 sale order via the XML-API with the following data:
{
  "carrier_id": 3,
  "client_order_ref": "13725",
  "company_id": 1,
  "name": "Order 13725",
  "note": "thanks :-)",
  "order_line": [
    [
      0,
      0,
      {
        "product_id": 101,
        "display_name": "Demo Product #1",
        "name": "Demo Product #1",
        "product_uom_qty": 1,
        "price_unit": 1,
        "price_tax": 0.07,
        "tax_id": [
          [
            6,
            0,
            [
              76
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  ],
  "partner_id": 13895
}

How can I use gross prices (taxes included) via API when the sale.order.line field price_total is read-only.
--
Edit 2024-08-20
One possibility to correct rounding errors would be to compare the total amounts and add a "Correction Position" as a sale.order.line that adds or subtracts the miss matching amount.
